# SVG 1.1 : What is "user unit" and how to convert user unit into absolute unit(eg: millimeter)?

Tags: svg, implementation

I am implementing SVG Tiny 1.1 and I am having trouble understanding the "user unit" concept.

SVG 1.1 specification defines every <length> with no specified unit (such as "mm", "cm", "pt", etc) to be in "user unit".

While implementing interface "SVGLength", I encountered 4 attributes related to the value of the length; `value`, `unityType`, `valueInSpecifiedUnit`, `valueAsString`. The last 3 attributes are clear enough for me.

1. `valueInSpecifiedUnit` is in unit type `unitType`.
2. `valueAsString` equals `valueInSpecifiedUnit`+`unitType`'s string value. Eg: "10mm"

However, the attribute *value* is said to be in user unit. So my questions are:

1. What is "user unit"?
2. how to convert from "user unit" to an "absolute unit" such as  millimeter (mm) ?

Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spec [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermUserUnits):

> **user units**
>
> A coordinate value or length expressed in user units
>   represents a coordinate value or length in the current user coordinate
>   system. Thus, 10 user units represents a length of 10 units in the
>   current user coordinate system.

Also:

> if the ‘width’ or ‘height’ attributes on the outermost svg element are in user units
>   (i.e., no unit identifier has been provided), then the value is assumed to be equivalent
>   to the same number of "px" units

which means that user units are the units specified in the outermost svg element's width and height attributes, and if they are not specified, then user units are pixels.

[Read the section on units in SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units).

Comment: So the "user unit" is defined in outmost svg element's width and heigth attributes.

Examples:
<svg width="20cm" heigth="10cm"> then user unit is "cm".
<svg width="200px" heigth="100px"> then user unit is "px".

Is this right ?

Comment: And then, is there a implicit conversion between pixels and mm? Is there somewhere an asumption on the DPI used in SVG documents? "Resolution" so to speak, even if we're talking vector.

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti No, the user unit is always equal to one `px`. Per the spec: "One px unit is defined to be equal to one user unit." The other units are scaled relative to the size of a `px`, i.e. `1mm` is always equal to `3.543307px` and equal to just `3.543307`.

Comment: The ratio given of 3.543307px per mm equates to 90dpi which is what Inkscape used to use, but I believe the common standard these days is 96dpi or 3.779527559. The SVG standard seems to avoid linking the user units with physical units, so it very much depends on the resolution of the implementation - so OP it is up to you depending on the DPI you choose.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is true. It seems me that if you specify the outer `<svg>` element's width and height in CM, the user units will be in CM.

Comment: Do the comments contradict the answer? It seems like these 3 statements cannot all be true: (1) “User units are the units specified in the outermost svg element's width and height attributes”, (2) “One px unit is defined to be equal to one user unit”, and (3) “1mm is always equal to 3.543307px”.